# Automatically alter C# WSDL generated code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, code-generation, build-process

In Visual Studio, is there a way to automatically alter source code and add a specific attribute to methods either prior to building or as part of the build process?  Similar to code generation except I'm not generating the code, it already exists.  Can something like T4 handle this?  I don't want to manually add these attributes, I want it to be an automatic, repeatable process.

For example:

```
public class Test
{
    public void MethodOne()
    {
    }

    public void MethodTwo()
    {
    }
}
```

Automatically becomes:

```
public class Test
{
    [CustomAttribute]
    public void MethodOne()
    {
    }

    [CustomAttribute]
    public void MethodTwo()
    {
    }
}
```

**Background:**

I'm using a 3rd party product called Xamarin to build Android + iOS apps using .NET. I'm consuming a SOAP web service using WSDL.exe to automatically generate a proxy. I've added an a custom web service SOAP extension on the client side and the only reliable way I've found of wiring up that custom extension is adding a custom attribute to each web service method generated in the client web service proxy. I have to repeat this process each time I update the web service proxy since it generates fresh code each time.

Couple notes about Xamarin limitations. I don't have access to a web.config or app.config file, which is the normal way of wiring up custom web service SOAP extensions. Xamarin doesn't support web.config or app.config files. I can't use newer technologies like WCF because Xamarin doesn't fully support them (support is still in beta and I've encountered some bugs that prevented me from using them)

Comment: How would the automatic tool know what attributes to apply and which methods to apply them to?

Comment: Well I assume the tool, if it exists, would have to allow for some sort of "coding" or "scripting" that allows me to define that.

Comment: So you mean, exactly like using Find/Replace with a regular expression?

Comment: Yes like Find/Replace with regular expressions only I'd like it to be automatic.

Comment: Well, that then begs the question: *why not use Find/Replace with a regular expression to accomplish what you want?*

Comment: One way to do this would be to execute a powershell script on the build event which finds/replaces for you, though this would be very custom to your project folder and file structure.

Comment: The answer is somewhat complicated.  I'm using a 3rd party product called Xamarin to build Android + iOS apps using .NET.  I'm consuming a SOAP web service using WSDL.exe to automatically generate a proxy.  I've added an a custom web service extension on the client side and the only reliable way I've found of wiring up that custom extension is adding a custom attribute to each web service method generated in the client web service proxy.  I have to repeat this process each time I update the web service proxy since it generates fresh code each time.

Comment: Couple notes about Xamarin limitations.  I don't have access to a web.config or app.config file, which is the normal way of wiring up custom web service extensions.  Xamarin doesn't support web.config or app.config files.
I can't use newer technologies like WCF because Xamarin doesn't fully support them (support is still in beta and I've encountered some bugs that prevented me from using them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished this using your test class. I'm on Visual Studio 2010, but assume it'll work in 2012.

Open up a Find/Replace window. Switch to the Quick Replace tab. Make sure Use Regular Expressions is checked under Find Options.

Enter this for Find What:

```
public void Method
```

Enter this for Replace With:

```
[CustomAttribute]\n\tpublic void Method
```

Comment: This is my current approach.  I guess there's really no better alternative other than involving PowerShell and I'm not ready to do that just yet.